# Can my question be lifted out of hold status? Can you specifically tell me how to improve it, because I have edited it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closing-questions

I have a question about my Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange post: [What's so special about Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199940/whats-so-special-about-harry-potter)

Comment: Now that you've clarified it, I have voted to reopen.  You *may* want to put more detail into this meta post, however, because it's a bit short.  People may not be able to see what's going on just from the title and link to your main-site question.

Comment: As your question has now been reopened, I've tagged this [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Randal'Thor Is "status-completed" normally used for this kind of request? It seems a bit odd, because there's no reason that the question can't be reclosed.

Answer (score 6):

Once your post has been edited, it automatically gets flagged for review, and the community will (eventually) get to look over the changes and vote to reopen it, or make further recommendations. On this site, we have high enough activity that it does not usually take very long for that to happen. You generally won't need to take any more action yourself beyond "fixing" the post, you just may have to wait a while. Especially on a weekend, I'd give at least a few days as activity drops off then.

If your post isn't getting reopened, or if you aren't sure *why* it was put on hold, or you disagree with some of the changes, then definitely come to this site to ask why. If you do that, though, you should put more detail in your post (e.g. were you told why it was on hold? What "reason code" did you see, and what did you do to fix it and/or why do you disagree?) so that users have some context. As long as you have a link to your question *somewhere* in your post, you can add whatever other information you think is helpful even if your reputation is low at the time.

In this case it looks like your edits were exactly what was needed and the post has been reopened.

Comment: And now answered.

Comment: Good answer. I'd just add a couple of points to explain why the OP posted on meta like this: 1) there's a comment on the question (now obsolete and deleted) from a high-rep user specifically suggesting they ask on meta to appeal the closure; 2) since the user had less than 5 rep, [they were *required*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/278659) to ask this meta in the form "*I have a question about my post: <link>*".

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's all well and good, but they still forgot to add the actual *question*, which the template explicitly asks for.